# Protothreads in C++

Tags: c++, timer, event-handling, embedded, protothread

Hi i am working on embedded system which controls a elevator through serial bus.
Every time i send a message (packet contains adress,data length, data, crc) i need to wait for elevator response, which is represented by acknowledgement packet.

ACK is set every time when I receive packet from elevator.
Receiving messages is done through Interrupt.
ACK packet looks like:

```
0xA0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00
```

and when it comes I set ACK to `true`

Here is my send function:

```
bool TransferService::send(char recAddr,char dataLength, char *data){
     pc.putc(startByte);
     pc.putc(recAddr);
     pc.putc(controllerAddress);
     pc.putc(dataLength);
     for (int i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
       pc.putc(data[i]);
     }
     pc.putc(getCrc(recAddr,controllerAddress,data, dataLength));
     _messageReceived = false;
     timer.reset();
     timer.start();
     ACK = false;
     do {
       if (ACK) {
         break;
       }
     } while(timer.read_ms()<=15);
     timer.stop();
     if (!ACK) {
       send(recAddr,dataLength,data);
     }
}
```

This is only try, it not work.

```
bool TransferService::send(char recAddr,char dataLength, char *data){
PT_BEGIN();
  timer.reset();
  timer.start();
  do {
    pc.putc(startByte);
    pc.putc(recAddr);
    pc.putc(controllerAddress);
    pc.putc(dataLength);
    for (int i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
      pc.putc(data[i]);
    }
    pc.putc(getCrc(recAddr,controllerAddress,data, dataLength));
    _messageReceived = false;
    PT_WAIT_UNTIL(!timer.read_ms() <=10 || ACK);
  } while(timer.read_ms() <=10);
  PT_END();
}
```

My question is how to make first function work correctly using protothreads.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: So, what, exactly, is your problem? _it not work_ is not a useful problem description.

Comment: "Protothreads" may refer to a [general concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protothreads) or a [specific implementation](http://dunkels.com/adam/pt/).  Your code appare to be using teh Adam Dunkels implementation, but your question should be clear about that - otherwise you may get answers including prototread implementations, which is presumably not what you want?

Comment: The first example uses recursion very ill-advisedly; the second does not appear to be equivalent and will I believe send repeatedly for 10ms so long as ACK is set.  With that and the misapplication of Protothreads, it is hard to see know what you are asking specifically.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of a thread function in [Adam Dunkels' implementation](http://dunkels.com/adam/pt/) of Protothreads is quite clear, and your function clearly does not follow it.

A Protothread thread function must return `int` and *normally* has the signature:

```
int threadfunction( struct pt* pt ) ;
```

and must be defined using the `PT_THREAD` macro thus:

```
PT_THREAD( threadfunction( struct pt* pt ) )
{
    PT_BEGIN(pt) ;
    // thread body here
    PT_END(pt) ;
}
```

From the *Protothread* documentation...

> A protothread function must always return an integer, but must never
>   explicitly return - returning is performed inside the protothread
>   statements.

Looking at the definition of `PT_THREAD` I can see nothing that would prevent its use with a C++ member function, or the use of additional arguments other than `pt`, in which case, the following is closer to correct:

```
PT_THREAD( TransferService::send( struct pt* pt, char recAddr, char dataLength, char *data )
{
    PT_BEGIN( pt );
    timer.reset();
    timer.start();

    pc.putc( startByte );
    pc.putc( recAddr );
    pc.putc( controllerAddress );
    pc.putc( dataLength );
    for( int i = 0; i < dataLength; i++ )
    {
        pc.putc( data[i] );
    }
    pc.putc( getCrc( recAddr, controllerAddress, data, dataLength ) );
    _messageReceived = false;

    PT_WAIT_UNTIL( pt, timer.read_ms() > 10 || ACK );

    PT_END();
}
```

In your attempt you had both a do-while loop and a `PT_WAIT_UNTIL`, but the WAIT makes the loop unnecessary.  It is not in fact necessary to pass the `pt` argument, the required `struct pt` might be a class member or even a global (although that would be ill-advised).

Note that the above follows the pattern evident in the question, but would be an unusual design pattern; most often a thread runs indefinitely rather than for a single transaction. Without knowledge of your entire application, I would suggest that the *thread* should operate at a higher level than the single transaction`send()` function, such that you have a "sender" thread that can repeatedly perform send operations without exiting as in the following *outline* (i.e. not complete or "real" code, and with a great many assumptions):

```
// Constructor...
TransferService::TransferService()
{
    PT_INIT( &m_pt ) ;  // Where thread state m_pt 
                        // is a member variable of
                        // type struct pt (or just pt 
                        // since this is C++)
    ...
}

// Thread function
PT_THREAD(TransferService::senderThread() )
{
  PT_BEGIN(&m_pt);     
  for(;;)
  {
      PT_WAIT_UNTIL( &m_pt, ready_to_send ) ;

      timer.reset();
      timer.start();
      send( recAddr, dataLength, data ) ;

      PT_WAIT_UNTIL( &m_pt, timer.read_ms() > 10 || ACK );
  }
  PT_END(pt);
}

// Single send transaction function
bool TransferService::send( char recAddr, char dataLength, char *data )
{
    pc.putc( startByte );
    pc.putc( recAddr );
    pc.putc( controllerAddress );
    pc.putc( dataLength );
    for( int i = 0; i < dataLength; i++ )
    {
        pc.putc( data[i] );
    }
    pc.putc( getCrc( recAddr, controllerAddress, data, dataLength ) );
    _messageReceived = false;
}
```

Note that due to the manner in which the `PT_...` API works, the `PT_WAIT_UNTIL` must be in the same function as the `PT_BEGIN` and `PT_END`, hence moving the timer wait in the code above.

Comment: A note about this answer:  I have never used Dunkels' *Protothreads*; I just read the documentation... just then.  You may get a better answer form someone who has *actually used* the library.  The code presented may or may not resolve your problem; a working thread schedule needs more than just the code presented, but it is no doubt a lot closer than that presented in the question (which also omits the scheduling code - it is not clear whether there *is any* scheduling code, if not that too is a problem, but at that point I suggest reading the documentation.